# CDK pipeline to deploy to S3 bucket from GitHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-cdk

I am trying to write cdk pipeline to setup s3 website whenever I commit to my github.
I was able to setup the static website using CDK.
however I am not sure how to progress with cdk pipeline to copy github repo contents to s3 bucket whenever there is a commit.

I was wondering if anyone can provide some guidance on the following

1. How to setup "Start the pipeline on source code change"
2. How to deploy (copy) the repo contents to S3 bucket

```js
    import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
    import * as codecommit from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-codecommit";
    import * as pipelines from "aws-cdk-lib/pipelines";
    import { CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource } from "aws-cdk-lib/pipelines";
    
    import { Construct } from "constructs";
    
    export class WorkshopPipeLineStack extends cdk.Stack {
      constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
    
        const source = pipelines.CodePipelineSource.gitHub(
          "kasukur/s3-website",
          "main"
        );
    
        const pipeline = new pipelines.CodePipeline(scope, "MyPipeline", {
          synth: new pipelines.ShellStep("Synth", {
            input: source,
            commands: [],
            env: {
              COMMIT_ID: source.sourceAttribute("CommitId"),
            },
          }),
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does the pipeline do anything else?  Specifically, does it deploy a CDK app?

Comment: It needs to deploy(copy) the GitHub repo contents to an existing S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use a `codepipeline.Pipeline` construct with a [S3 Deploy Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.S3DeployAction.html).

---

You've got the wrong tool for the job.  The `pipelines.CodePipeline` construct (aka CDK Pipeline) is a specialist pipeline construct for [deploying CDK apps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html).  That's not what you want<sup>1</sup>.  Instead, use the [codepipeline.Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline-readme.html) construct, a more general-purpose tool<sup>2</sup>.   A `pipelines.CodePipeline` consists of stages.  Stages have actions:

**Source Action**: [GitHubSourceAction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.GitHubSourceAction.html) using your GitHub OAuth token in Secrets Manager or the newer [CodeStarConnectionAction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.CodeStarConnectionsSourceAction.html) that uses a CodeStar connection (= GitHub app) to connect to your repo.

**[Build Actions, Test Actions]**

**Deploy Action**:  a [S3DeployAction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline_actions.S3DeployAction.html) outputs your artefact to S3

---

1. Each CDK Pipeline stage *must contain* at least one CDK stack or will fail on synth.
2. If you just need a simple copy-paste from GitHub to S3 on a commit, a standalone CodeBuild project configured for [Github](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.GitHubSourceCredentials.html) can do the job without a pipeline.

Comment: Thank you so much @fedonev. I am fairly new to this, so your answer has helped me a lot in completing this and also learnt a lot.