# Deploy Python Lambda with TypeScript CDK

Tags: python, typescript, git, aws-cdk

I am new to aws-cdk, trying to deploy a lambda for the first time. I created 2 git repo to keep infra and python scripts separately. 1 Python git repo to store all python scripts required for lambda. 1 typescript git repo to deploy infra using cdk. In my cdk app, I added a prebuild step which will check basic linting, pytest test cases. once deployed, i can see my entire python repo is zipped and present in s3 bucket created by cdk at location 'artifactBucket/MyPipeLineName/bharath-t/ONvvlDC.zip'. PipelineStage internally deploys a lambda stack. How can i access python repo s3 zip location within the stack and pass it to pipelinestage which inturn will be used by lambdastack?

```
import { Stack, StackProps, aws_lambda } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { CodePipeline, CodePipelineSource, ShellStep } from 'aws-cdk-lib/pipelines';
import { PipelineStage } from './PipelineStage';
import path = require('path');


export class AwsCdkLearnStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const source = CodePipelineSource.gitHub('bharath-t/aws-cdk-learn', 'main');
    const python_source = CodePipelineSource.gitHub('bharath-t/python-learn', 'main');

    const prebuild = new ShellStep('Prebuild', {
      input: python_source,
      primaryOutputDirectory: './src',
      commands: ['pip install flake8 pytest build', 'flake8 --exit-zero', 'pytest'],
    });

    const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'TestPipeline', {
      pipelineName: 'TestPipeline',
      synth: new ShellStep('Synth', {
        input: source,
        additionalInputs: {
          '../siblingdir': prebuild,
        },
        commands: ['npm ci', 'npx cdk synth'],
      })
    });

    const betaStage = new PipelineStage(this, 'BetaStage', {
      stageName: 'beta',
    });


    pipeline.addStage(betaStage);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you're trying to build the lambda zip file in a ShellStep using one repo and then use the zipped file in subsequent pipeline stages for your lambda deployment which are sourced from another repo.

How CodePipeline works is that it will actually pass files from one stage to the next. So if you look at the second build stage (the `synth` step) and add an `ls` to the commands, you will see the output of the pre-build ShellStep.
I copied your file an and tested it and in your case, the `synth` stage indeed has two inputs:

```
  - Name: bharath_t_aws_cdk_learn_Source (the repo with your cdk code)
  - Name: Prebuild_Output (the output from the pre-build step)
```

In your CDK stack containing the lambda, you can point to the zipfile on the local filesystem `code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '../path/to/lambda'))`.

Two things to think about:

- The exact folder location of where the second input is stored is a bit of trial and error (I keep forgetting this as well). It is documented somewhere.
- CodePipeline unzips your files in the `synth` step. So you won't be looking for a zipfile but an entire directory of files.

Now why is that file in S3 then you might say? That's how CodePipeline gets files from build step 1 to the next. It stores the output 'temporarily' in S3 and then provides it as input for the next build. It's not meant to be accessed directly by other systems, except for debugging maybe.

Comment: as per this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75082169/cdk-pipeline-to-deploy-to-s3-bucket-from-github), we need to use aws_codepipeline instead of pipelines.

Comment: I don't think so as this post actually deploys a cdk app. So it needs pipelines, not aws_codepipeline